# Scheduling Python Script with two versions of Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I've got two versions of Python installed (2.7 and 3.5) via ArcGIS (Desktop 10.4 and Pro). I have multiple scripts that must run daily. The Python 2 scripts all run perfectly via Windows Task Scheduler, however, my Python 3 scripts simply refuse to run via the task scheduler.

I originally had them set to run from .bat files which works fine when operated manually.

```
@echo off
python3 \\Myserver\Pythonstuff\myscript.py
```

These .bat files will not operate via the task scheduler. Some things I've tried:

- set python3.exe as the program/script and add in the script location as the argument
- set cmd as the program/script and add python3 \Myserver\Pythonstuff\myscript.py as the argument

Nothing seems to work here. I need the other scripts to run in Python 2 and I can't mess everything up with them so I'd like to maintain their Python2/3 integrity between the scripts. Any ideas?

Comment: `where python3` returns `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` I'd use `py.exe` as `py -3 \\Myserver\Pythonstuff\myscript.py`

Comment: Python 3 from python.org doesn't install a `python3` command, so does "python3.exe" exist (could be a copy, link, or symlink; doesn't matter), or is that a "python3.lnk" shell shortcut or "python3.bat" batch script? If it's actually "python3.exe", try using the fully-qualified path.

Comment: I made a copy of Python.exe in my Python27 and Python35 folders and created an environment variable. So I can just call Python2/3 in cmd and it'll open the respective shell.